# how to return a row count for tableview from NSXMLParserdelegate methods?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser, asihttprequest

I am currently using the ASIHTTPRequest wrapper to connect to my database though a php script, basicly it queries the database then returns the result set in an xml format.

from there i instantiate my parser method which inturn passes all the requiered info to the NSXMLParserDelegate methods

```
//..
parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
//..
parser:foundCharacters:
//..
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
//..
```

The data is first of all passed through a NSMutableData variable when the initial steam of data comes down.

I then have an if statment in my parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes: that passes all the data into the string on the basis of the condition

```
if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]) {
        // NSLog(@"Found title!");
        itemString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
```

from here I am wondering how I set the row count of the tableview inside the numberOfSectionsInTableView method? what variable would I call count on or would I have to create something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is great tutorial for parsing XML in Apple Sample Source Code 
It's called SeismicXML

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8

in your question you have the error: numberOfSectionsInTableView didn't return the row count - it's return sections count. In most casesif you have ordinary tableview it should return 1.

and this code return number of rows in this section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [YOUR_ARRAY count];
}
```

Comment: cheers cant believe i did that with the section count, however thats still not fixing the problem of the fact that the view is loading before the parsing has processed so no data is being shown.

Comment: yes, at first your array is empty and there are no rows in it, so [your_array count] return 0. but when your parse operation will end and you populate your array with data, you need to ask your tableview to reload data as Leaner mentioned - [your_table_view reloadData]; if you show us more code we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding you question following will help.

1 Hope you are already saving all values of items in some array in elementDidEnd method.

2 Write some code like following. 


        `if([parser parse]){
        [tableView reloadData];
    }`

This will reload table once parsing is done.

3 Return count of array in which you stored all the item values and fill the table  with that array.

Please post if you need any more help.

Comment: Yea I am putting my results into an array now and calling the count on that inside the tablerow count thingy.. but its calling that before anything is parsed so the rows are not showing.. that peice of code didnt work out.. so not sure what else to do.

Comment: Then you can try this. 1. in didEndElement method put one extra if condition for last tag of your XML. 2. When last tag is encountered there reload the table. This will make sure that your table is getting reloaded after XML is parsed(You might have to call that method in performSelector). Please make sure that you are filling your table with proper array because above method is working here in my code. If it still don't work then post some code you used for loading the table.

Comment: +reload means that you are calling some static method. make sure you are calling a method with instance if UITableView not with UITAbleView class itself.